# ruby single word pig latin with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Calling forth ruby regex masters!

I am trying to solve this problem in ruby using regex. The input will be a single word. Two conditions apply:

- If it starts with vowels [aeiou], it returns the word + 'way'. For example, `pig_latin('aye') #=> 'ayeway'`
- If it starts with consonants, it moves the first letter of the word to the end of string, then + 'ay'. `pig_latin('map') #=> 'apmay'`

I have tried:

```
def pig_latin(ay)
    ay.gsub(/\A[aeiou](w+)/, '\2\1way')
end

pig_latin('map') #=> 'map'
pig_latin('aye') #=> 'aye'
```

When I tried

```
ay.gsub(/^[aeiou](\w+)*/, '\2\1way')
pig_latin('map') #=> 'map'
pig_latin('aye') #=> 'yeway'
```

Getting close. At least it recognizes consonants - but it removes 'a' in 'aye'.

I have tried reading regex doc, especially on [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) and [rubular](http://rubular.com/) helps to illuminate a bit, but I am still in the dark ages.

Comment: you need to do it only with 1 gsub call?

Comment: Do you need to use regex?

Comment: @CarlMarkham technically I don't. But I have solved something similar without regex. I wanted to challenge myself and limit myself to use as much regex as/if possible. But any solution is always welcome! I can always learn something from other people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case two `gsub` calls are allowed:

```
def pig_latin(ay)
    ay[0] =~ /[aeiou]/ ? ay.gsub(/([aeiou])(\w+)*/, '\1\2way') : ay.gsub(/([^aeiou])(\w+)*/, '\2\1ay')
end

pig_latin("aye") #=> ayeway
pig_latin("map") #=> apmay
```

In case two `gsub` calls are not allowed:

```
def pig_latin(ay)
    ay += ( (ay[0] =~ /[aeiou]/).nil? ? "" : "w")
    ay.gsub(/([^aeiou]?)([aeiou])(\w+)(.?)/, '\2\3\1\4ay')
end

pig_latin("aye") #=> ayeway
pig_latin("map") #=> apmay
```

Comment: We appreciate that you're happy to help, but please don't put salutations, valedictions or signatures in questions or answers. SO is like a reference book, not a discussion forum. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/153968 and the related links discuss this.

Comment: @theTinMan thank you for drawing my attention. I will try to stay away from my this habit ! : )

Answer (score 1):

If you do not **need** to use regex you could do the following

```
pig_latin 'aye'

def pig_latin word
  if word[0].in? ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    return word << 'way'
  else
    first = word.strip[0] # Get the first letter
    word = word.sub first, '' # remove the first letter from word
    return word << first << 'ay'
  end
end
```